# Move my wordpress site from openshift to another server

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

I moved my wordpress from Openshift to another server. Howerver, It does not work, my website only display white page. I tried to change the Openshift variable into file wp-config.php, but it still not worked.
Can anyone please help me resolve this problem?

My wp-config.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configurations of the WordPress.
 *
 * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
 * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
 * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
 * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
 *
 * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
 * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'mydb');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'mydb');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mydb123');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'));

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */

// This is where we define the OpenShift specific secure variable functions
// This function gets called by openshift_secure and passes an array
function make_secure_key($args) {
  $hash = $args['hash'];
  $key  = $args['variable'];
  $original = $args['original'];

    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
  $chars .= '!@#$%^&*()';
  $chars .= '-_ []{}<>~`+=,.;:/?|';

  // Convert the hash to an int to seed the RNG
  srand(hexdec(substr($hash,0,8)));
  // Create a random string the same length as the default
  $val = '';
  for($i = 1; $i <= strlen($original); $i++){
    $val .= substr( $chars, rand(0,strlen($chars))-1, 1);
  }
  // Reset the RNG
  srand();
  // Set the value
  return $val;
}

// Generate OpenShift secure keys (or return defaults if not on OpenShift)
$array = openshift_secure($_default_keys,'make_secure_key');

// Loop through returned values and define them
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  define($key,$value);
}

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', 'vi');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/**
 * We prefer to be secure by default
 */
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
  define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Tell WordPress where the plugins directory really is */
if ( !defined('WP_PLUGIN_DIR') && is_link(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins') )
  define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', realpath(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins'));

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

/**define('WP_HOME','http://www.yode.vn');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.yode.vn');*/
```

Comment: Set debug mode to true (WP_DEBUG) and see if you get an error message. Also, it looks like there is some code that has been added to the config file that is specific to OpenShift. You may want to try using an unedited wp-config file.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I move Wordpress websites, I always backup the database first.

1) Install the current version of Wordpress on the new site and make sure it works.

2) Install the plugins and make sure it works.

3) Install the theme and make sure it works.

4) Then, import the database.

You shouldn't have to screw around with wp-config.php because step 1 took care of that.

Comment: I backup database and restore it in the new server first. If I have to install plugins and theme, this will spend a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
Generate new Keys and replace block started from `/**#@+` till `/**#@-*/`

Here is full instruction [how to migrate wordpress blog from OpenShift](http://druss.info/2015/01/migrate-wordpress-site-from-openshift-to-vps/)